# Function returned by callback to use closure to add additional param is not executing

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, fetch, react-redux

I am trying to use closure concept to for additional parameter in callback function. For some reason, it is not working. Following is code for reference.

```
export function loadConfigData(session) {

  return function(dispatch) {

    // API URL to get the config details
    const url = session.apiHost + '/config';

    const headers = {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',key: session.key};

// Make fetch API call to get the config data with same-origin to enable fetch to send the cookie with API call.
    return fetch(url,{credentials: 'same-origin',headers,method: 'GET'})
      .then(processAPIResponse)
      .then(loadConfigDataSuccessHandler)     
      .catch(loadConfigDataErrorHandler);
  }
}

export const processAPIResponse = (response)=> {
  if ( !response.ok ) {
    return Promise.reject(response);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(response.json());
};

export const loadConfigDataErrorHandler = (response)=> {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(receiveConfigError(new Error("Bad response from server")));
    return Promise.reject(response);
  };
};

export const loadConfigDataSuccessHandler = (configObj)=> {
  // Following function is not getting execute.
  return function(dispatch) {
  // In case of success, start action to update the data
  dispatch(receiveConfigData(configObj));
  // Resolve promise
  return Promise.resolve(configObj);
  };
};
```

Issue: For some reason, function returned by "loadConfigDataSuccessHandler" is not getting execute and because of that my business logic on success handler is not executing.

Note: This code snippet is from redux-action therefore please ignore use of "dispatch"

**UPDATED WORKING CODE WITH CALLBACK:**

To add more details, if do not use closure and to the callback then it works, however, I think it is not a clean approach. Following is callback approach which works.

```
export const loadConfigDataSuccessHandler = (configObj,dispatch)=> {

  // In case of success, start action to update the data
  dispatch(receiveConfigData(configObj));
  return configObj;
};

export const loadConfigDataErrorHandler = (response,dispatch)=> {
  dispatch(receiveConfigError(new Error("Bad response from server")));
  return response;
};

export function loadConfigData(session) {

  return function(dispatch) {

    // Request to load the user data, set loading flag is true to show loading screen
    dispatch(requestConfigData());

    // API URL to get the user details
    const url = session.apiHost + API_CONTEXT_PATH + '/config';

    const headers = getHTTPHeader(session.blueboxpublic,session.blueboxvalues);
    // Make fetch API call to get the user data with same-origin to enable fetch to send the cookie with API call.
    return fetch(url,{credentials: 'same-origin',headers,method: 'GET'})
      .then(processAPIResponse)
      .then((configObj)=>loadConfigDataSuccessHandler(configObj,dispatch))
      .catch((configObj)=>loadConfigDataErrorHandler(configObj,dispatch))
      .catch(handleAPISystemDown)
      .catch(loadConfigDataErrorHandler);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI (it's not the problem), but in a `then` (or `catch`) callback, `return Promise.resolve(x);` is completely unnecessary; simply `return x;` is all you need.

Comment: Also note that `loadConfigDataErrorHandler` converts a rejection into a resolution with a function as its resolution value, which seems unlikely to be what you wanted...

Comment: Well, if you want to use those `function(dispatch)`s as the success/error handlers of the promise, you need to actually *call* the `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler`/`loadConfigDataErrorHandler` functions with a response argument to create the closures.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding around promises. Your various `then`/`catch` callbacks (`loadConfigDataSuccessHandler`, `loadConfigDataErrorHandler`; but not `processAPIResponse`) are **returning** functions. But the chain you've set up isn't doing anything to *call* those functions. So you just end up with a promise chain that ends up being resolved with a function that never gets called. I can't answer the question because I don't know anything about redux-action and so can't show how to use `dispatch`, but that's why it seems like those handlers aren't being called.

Comment: Actually "loadConfigDataSuccessHandler" is being called. When I added console log just before "return" then it is getting printed. However the function returned is not getting executed.

Comment: Hey @Bergi, are you talking about calling callback approach? I have added that approach in my details. I don't think that's clean approach.

Comment: No, I'm talking about your first snippet. You'd need to use `.then(loadConfigDataSuccessHandler(configObj)).catch(loadConfigDataErrorHandler(configObj));` to get the *inner* (returned) function to run.

Comment: ok, so how can I pass 'dispatch' into `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler` function?

Comment: Got it now:-) `.then(loadConfigDataSuccessHandler(dispatch))` and changed `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler` as `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler = (dispatch)=> {
  // Following function is not getting execute.
  return function(configObj) {
    // In case of success, start action to update the data
    dispatch(receiveConfigData(configObj));
    // Resolve promise
    return Promise.resolve(configObj);
  };
}`

Comment: its working :-) Thanks a lot Bergi :-)

Comment: These days we'd usually choose to use `.bind()` rather than closure to curry-up `dispatch` ... `configObj`.

Comment: Also, that tripple catch doesn't look right. Looking at `loadConfigDataErrorHandler`, I would guess you need a maximum of two catches and then only if `handleAPISystemDown` is asynchronous. Be sure to check out all that error handling by forcing errors.

Comment: `.bind`, not sure how can I use it in this use case? I can do `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler.bind(this,dispatch)` but how to pass `configObj` which is resolved promise?

Comment: Make sure `loadConfigDataSuccessHandler` has the signature `(dispatch, configObj)` *in that order*. In the promise chain, `.then(loadConfigDataSuccessHandler.bind(null, dispatch))` gives `.then()` a function which has `dispatch` bound-in, and which still expects `configObj`. That's all you need to do. It ends up very much like the line above, `.then(processAPIResponse)`, where `processAPIResponse` receives its (invisible) parameter on promise fulfillment.